# Unable to build the built-in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to build my first pipeline and using as an example the built-in Git Pipeline:

```
node {
   def mvnHome
   stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
      // Get some code from a GitHub repository
      git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
      // Get the Maven tool.
      // ** NOTE: This 'M3' Maven tool must be configured
      // **       in the global configuration.           
      mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   }
   stage('Build') {

      // Run the maven build
      if (isUnix()) {
         sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
      } else {
         bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package/)
      }
   }
   stage('Results') {
      junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      archive 'target/*.jar'
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, it fails with the following error:

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/user01/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Preparation)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
[mypipeline] Running shell script
+ /home/user01/apache/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.092 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-25T19:13:53+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/user01/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

The steps I've followed are the ones described in the Jenkins wiki, that is:

- Install the Pipeline plugin
- Define the Maven (M3) Tool in global configuration
- Configure JDK Path
- Configure Git Path

If I try to do:

```
ls /home/user01/.jenkins/workspace/mypipeline
```

it is indeed empty so the stage Preparation does not clone the project locally. Why ? What am I missing ? Thanks!!!

Comment: what is the console Output, does the git operation exposes anything. Do you get any error message

Comment: Can you add the console output... Did a git checkout happen ??

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full log. The only thing which happens is the directory creation ("simple-maven-project-with-tests") but nothing is cloned there. I've cloned manually with git and it works so there's something wrong with the 'git' command in the pipeline.